# How to detect scrolling through javascript, and immediately restore the original style when the web page is scrolled up?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have encountered a javaScript scrolling problem and want to ask everyone!

I have completed that when the web page scrolls down, the green block will change. When I want to scroll up the web page, the green block will instantly change back to the original Style!

But at present, he can only restore the original style when he returns to the top. How should I rewrite it so that the green block will restore to the original style when the page scrolls up?

Thank you for watching my question.

```js
let title = document.querySelector('.title');


function move(){
  let moveTo = (title.offsetTop) + (title.clientHeight /2);
  if(window.scrollY > moveTo){
    title.classList.add('fixedTop');
  }else{
    title.classList.remove('fixedTop');
  }
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', move);
```

```css
.content {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.content .wrap {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: auto;
}
.content .wrap .title {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #71ff05;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
}
.content .wrap .txt {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 3;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.content .wrap .fixedTop {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="wrap">
       <h1 class='title'>TITLE</h1>
       <p class='txt'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut eum repudiandae cum illum porro aperiam nulla, dicta amet laboriosam a quo iste repellat? Repudiandae ea quam nemo aperiam consequatur amet sint impedit libero corrupti, similique eligendi a numquam fugit sit quia accusantium blanditiis quasi asperiores optio nesciunt. Reprehenderit, ratione suscipit. Amet blanditiis odit veritatis, molestiae quod doloribus id dolore? Sequi earum odio molestiae fuga tenetur minus quia sapiente quae, eaque explicabo doloremque sit inventore quaerat nesciunt illo sed id! Dolorum illum sit aspernatur quaerat recusandae? Voluptatem accusamus soluta id similique quia nemo nisi ea ducimus numquam iste dolorum officiis corporis voluptate, sapiente nihil sunt error cupiditate, deserunt voluptas explicabo quas, nostrum culpa rem iusto. Rem veritatis eius, sequi nesciunt distinctio quis provident optio at tempore rerum beatae neque illo numquam. Unde at quidem autem, libero vel enim molestiae recusandae, atque, repudiandae minima est. Atque est quae voluptates unde itaque reprehenderit adipisci recusandae qui corporis excepturi commodi, enim esse? Corrupti illum eius soluta. Culpa et vero ratione temporibus alias dolores repudiandae provident pariatur blanditiis eum enim quod nostrum laborum, qui quisquam atque rerum sed. Soluta in omnis quod consequuntur! Voluptatem, perferendis. Culpa officiis numquam corporis explicabo reiciendis ipsam qui sequi. Reiciendis?</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you saying that as soon as the user starts to scroll up the title should go to the fixed position at the top of the viewport - regardless of whether they are scrolling up past the title or not?

Comment: Yes, what I want to achieve is when the user starts to scroll up, the green block will be restored to the default appearance~

instead of scrolling to the top to restore the default appearance, but I don’t know how to achieve it!

Comment: You'd need to track the previous scroll position in order to detect the direction of the scroll.

Comment: @Ouroborus
I'm sorry that I am a beginner in programming and I don't know how to write the trace you said.